# Modifying DynamoDB object model in iOS app

Tags: ios, objective-c, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

I have an mobile app using AWS Mobile iOS SDK that is already in production. The app uses DynamoDB for directly storing and retrieving user data (without any API layer in  between). Now I want to modify an existing DynamoDB object model in the app by adding a new field. The new app version will work perfectly fine to store and retrieve data based on this new DynamoDB model. My question is whether this addition of the new field would impact current app version using the old DynamoDB object model? Will it cause crash the current app version due to missing field in old DynamoDB object model?

**Example:**

Let’s say I have a class named MyUserObject drives from AWSDynamoDBObjectModel, with fields 'name', and 'email'.

```
@interface MyUserObject : AWSDynamoDBObjectModel <AWSDynamoDBModeling>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;

@end
```

Now I want to add another field 'country' in the MyUserObject class:

```
@interface MyUserObject : AWSDynamoDBObjectModel <AWSDynamoDBModeling>

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *email;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *country;

@end
```

So, will this addition impact the current app version using the old DynamoDB object model?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The short answer is, no.

DynamoDB is a schema-less store.

- During reads: if client's `AWSDynamoDBObjectModel` has more attributes than what are there in DynamoDB or vice versa, the extra attributes are ignored.
- During writes: There are 4 different save behavior options as documented [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/mobile/sdkforios/developerguide/dynamodb-nosql-database-for-ios.html#save-behavior-options). The default one, `AWSDynamoDBObjectMapperSaveBehaviorUpdate`, leaves the unmodeled attributes unaffected and should work fine for your use case.